# Split HTML file by <section>, into separate include files?

Tags: html, scripting, include, transformation, server-side-includes

I want to split a HTML file, by the `<section>` tag, into separate files.

An example might be:

`mypage.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         ...
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- Section 1 -->
    <section class="foo">
        ...
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section class="bar">
        ...
    </section>

    <!-- Section 3 -->
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The desired outcome would then be enumerated as so:

```
/mypage.html            # (original file)
/mypage-split.html      # (original file, with placeholders to replace the section back in)

# component/include files (that of course will not be valid HTML, since it's just a portion and won't start with `DOCTYPE` or `html`)
/sections/mypage-1.htmlinc      # (section 1 markup)
/sections/mypage-2.inc          # (section 2 markup)
...
/sections/mypage-n.html
```

*How can I perform this split?*

A shell script might be the easiest way, but my scripting skill is very limited.

Or, *is there any web standard to keep components of HTML pages in separated files* (supported by browsers or web-servers), without having to resort on a web programming language? (server or client side)

Comment: The `<!-- Section 1 -->` comments are in the actual file, perhaps a solution would be to use regex to find all section comments and retrieve the content in between. The only problem would be the last section, hm..

Comment: Do you search for someone for writing the program for you? In this case, I suggest that you post it [here](https://www.peopleperhour.com/). If you prefer writing it by yourself, choose that language you are most familiar with, and post the code you have, up to the point you got stuck.

Comment: @user1934428 I completely understand your stance, although it a bit harsh. I was simply asking for suggestions on the best way before I spend hours on this trivial task, later to find out that there was a simple program that could have done it for me in 5 seconds. If you look at my question history I have never asked people to code for me. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be harsh, just a serious recommendation. An acquaintance once suggested to me to give away small programming tasks to freelancers for a quick and inexpensive solution, and I think this is a good business model for both parties. At  [so] we discuss concrete programming problems, and this means that we nee to see some code from your side.

Comment: @user1934428 Gotcha. Appreciate the heads up! It's been years since my last question, apologies for forgetting the Stack etiquette.

Comment: Since you asked for a suggestion: If you can ensure that the _Section_ lines are always on a line on their own, just read the file in a loop and copy the lines to their current section file. Of the languages you mentioned in the text, `bash` would perhaps be a good choice. Of the languages you mentioned in your tags, probably Powershell would be the way to go. If I would do it, I would most likely use Ruby or zsh. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: Suggestions require opinion, and questions which require opinion based answers are off topic on StackOverflow. _(Not harsh, just the reality of the guidance for this particular site)_.

Comment: imho a little picky on words. Now is edited to be a standard question, focused on a single need, ask for precise outcomes and for actual solutions, rather than suggestions. –  Please consider voting for reopening.

Comment: I'd love to know there is a solution, without relying on PHP or JS. – But I am afraid that the only clean/stable solution is to use XML, XInclude and XSLT for transforming to HTML format (or worse: HTML -> XML + XInclude, perform changes in XML, and then XML + XSLT -> HTML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tag=section
sed -n "/<$tag>/,/<\/$tag>/p" section.inc
```

This should be a starting point for you:
you can specify the target HTML tag name into the `tag` environment variable;
`sed` will extract the file content delimited by your tag and put it into the filepath

Comment: I didn't try, but this will probably fail when you have a tag inside the same tag.
Regex are not a good fit to parse hierarchical structures.